# Specify attachment encoding for couchdb

Tags: python, unicode, couchdb

I have the following test script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import couchdb

GREEK = u'ΑΒΓΔ ΕΖΗΘ ΙΚΛΜ ΝΞΟΠ ΡΣΤΥ ΦΧΨΩ αβγδ εζηθ ικλμ νξοπ ρςτυ φχψω'

# Prepare a unicode file, encoded using ENCODING
ENCODING = 'utf-8'
filename = '/tmp/test'
open(filename, 'w').write(GREEK.encode(ENCODING))

# Create an empty document
server = couchdb.Server()
db = server['cdb-tests']
doc_id = 'testing'
doc = { }
db[doc_id] = doc

# Attach the file to the document
content = open(filename, 'rb') # Open the file for reading
db.put_attachment(doc, content, content_type='text/plain')
```

As you can see, the file is utf-8 encoded, but when I attach that file to couchdb, I have no way to specify this encoding. Thus, requesting the attachment at `http://localhost:5984/cdb-tests/testing/test` returns the following Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: CouchDB/1.2.0 (Erlang OTP/R15B01)
ETag: "7y85tiUeF/UX9kqpKAzQEw=="
Date: Fri, 03 Jan 2014 13:43:36 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-MD5: 7y85tiUeF/UX9kqpKAzQEw==
Content-Length: 102
Content-Encoding: gzip
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Accept-Ranges: none
```

Seeing the attachment with a browser shows complete gibberish. How can I store the encoding for couchdb attachments?

Comment: I don't have worked with couchdb, but have you tried with `codecs` module and `codecs.open`. `codecs.open` spawn objects with file-like interface and allows you to specify encoding.

Answer (score 4):

As advised in the couchdb mailing list, the solution is to do:

```
db.put_attachment(doc, content, content_type='text/plain;charset=utf-8')
```